# Android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: Dexpathlist

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I am facing the below error, and I have tried almost each and every solution from Stackoverflow. I am new to android, so may be I am not understanding the cause.
I am testing a libgdx project from the by following the instructions:    https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29

I installed the the below mentioned tools in the sequence:

1. JDK (java version 1.8.0.73)
2. Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).
3. SDK (I have SDK tools 24.4.1 and SDK build tools 23.0.2 and 23.0.1)
4. Android development tools for Eclipse from the URL within eclipse: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
5. Gradle 2.11 - I unzipped gradle-all-2.11.zip and kept on my local machine.

Now, when I generate a very basic sample libgdx project using gdx-setup.jar, and name the package my-gdx-game, it created a desktop version(java application) and an android version(android application)

I use Build tools V 23.0.1 while building the project through the jar. My eclipse screen looks like this:

[image: Eclipse]
When I right click on my-gdx-game-desktop and Run as Java application, it runs successfully and displays and image(project is all about displaying an image).

Now, for the android project, I created a AVD - Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2(api 19), CPU: ARM(armeabi-v7a), use host GPU. My manifest.xml file is as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Project> Properties> Android: only Android 4.4.2 is selected(API 19)

Now, when I right click on project>run as> android application, the AVD opens up and the below error is generated:

```
03-08 13:44:35.110: W/dalvikvm(1968): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mygdx/game/AndroidLauncher; (3)
03-08 13:44:35.110: W/dalvikvm(1968): Link of class 'Lcom/mygdx/game/AndroidLauncher;' failed
03-08 13:44:35.110: D/AndroidRuntime(1968): Shutting down VM
03-08 13:44:35.120: W/dalvikvm(1968): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ae4ba8)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 1968
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mygdx.game-1, /system/lib]]
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mygdx.game-1, /system/lib]]
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
03-08 13:44:35.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     ... 11 more
03-08 13:49:35.320: I/Process(1968): Sending signal. PID: 1968 SIG: 9
```

[image: My project Build path]

I have tried a lot of answers from stackoverflow, but none seems to work in my case. Please help.

Comment: Check project and external dependencies.

Comment: When I do that, the above error goes, but another one comes in: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So now the issue is resolved.

1. My project and external dependencies are checked now.
2. My manifest.xml has android:name=".AndroidLauncher" now.
3. Changing the Eclipse java version to 1.7 worked for me. In Eclipse, go to Windows->Preferences->Java->Compiler and set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.7.

3rd step was the game changer for me.
Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the path of your activity. Try this in your manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name=".AndroidLauncher"
```

Because probably you have this above

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mygdx.game"
```

Answer (score 0):

I will also describe my case, where I was trying to use one project as "library" (by including all sources in my second project). Just adding sources as projects (one is core and one is android) to build path resulted in the same error as mentioned before (didn't find class etc.)

To ensure, that my second Android project is ok, I needed to not only include source folders in "Properties->Java Build Path->Projects", but I also needed to go to "Order and Export" tab, move "core" and "android" entries to the top and check them (where by default, they are unchecked). After all of that, my Android application works like a charm.

So, if you are using existing project to build another one and previously posted solutions didn't work, maybe my solution will help (I spent almost a half of day trying to find a proper solution for my scenario...)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when trying to run my android app from Eclipse using LibGDX.

I had also tried the previous mentioned steps:

```
My project and external dependencies are checked now.
My manifest.xml has android:name=".AndroidLauncher" now.
Changing the Eclipse java version to 1.7 worked for me. In Eclipse, go to Windows->Preferences->Java->Compiler and set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.7.
```

The extra step of checking the following boxes in my Java Build Path->Order and Exports fixed both the dalvik error and the missing class. It seemed that my issue of Dalvik Error 1 was coming from the Android Private Libraries. The class not found fixed after the GDX Order and Exports were checked.

[image: Java Build Path: Order and Exports]

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing of the above mentioned solutions applied. Today I am using Eclipse Oxygen and Java 1.8. LibGDX project setup just makes a small mistake to make it not runnable out of the box:

1. Nor manifest or java version must be changed.
2. Build Path of the android project must be changed in the tab "Order and Export" you must also check "Project and External Dependencies".

[Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0d1d.png)